# Serve files without exposing directory structure in Django

Tags: python, django

Right now, for every `Foo` object in my database I have related file that is being stored in path that has following structure `some/example/path/foo/pk/name.txt`.

The default way of serving them in Django would be by specifying `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` in settings. This way, I could access file related with `Foo object with id=1` by visiting `localhost:8000/media/foo/1/name.txt` and similar way for other objects.

But I would prefer not to expose to user how the files are stored internally (directory structure, primary keys etc.) and serve them from `localhost:8000/media/mapped_path_to_name.txt`.

For now, the only solution I can think of is to create custom view responsible for serving files and in this view put logic that does paths mapping. Is there any more elegant(minimalistic) solution to this problem?

Comment: What's inelegant about what you suggest? Seems like the best way to solve this problem.

Comment: Agreed. As soon as I saw the title I though "custom view to serve the file".

Comment: My reasoning was that it is done automatically by Django, just needs a few configuration lines and I thought that there could some kind of middleware-like settings that will help to achieve this. But if you both say that it's the best option, I'll go with that. Should I write this view from scratch or somehow adapt the solution used by Django, what's your recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is X-Sendfile for Apache or X-Accel-Redirect for Nginx. Django would take all the requests for the static files and have it internally redirected to a requested file so that a user cannot see the real path nor the filename. It's a common solution to send protected files via a webserver after a successful authentication by the application server.

As an example in Nginx you set an internal alias and a files' real location:

```
location ^~ /protected_files/ {
   internal;
   alias /real/location/protected_files/;
}
```

and in a Django view you make a response with an internal redirect and other information about the file:

```
file_path = 'real/path/to/the/file' # you should have your way to get it from url
filename = 'filename-used-to-save-the-file'
response = HttpResponse()
content_type, encoding = mimetypes.MimeTypes().guess_type(full_path)
response['Content-Type'] = content_type
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename
response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected_files/%s' % file_path
```

The urls you provide your users with can be whatever you put in your urls.py that is routing them to the view

You can read more on X-Accel-Redirect at:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/

Comment: Should the last line not be `response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected_files/%s' % filename`?

Comment: @jojo: No, in my example the file_path is the full path to the file with a real filename. The filename variable in the example is the name the user gets when downloading the file (trying to save it locally).